# Re-stream icecast stream through nodejs

Tags: node.js, icecast

Play our icecast stream through Nodejs, so that I can read metadata and push another audio file at key parts.

What I am wondering is why the following script won't allow a user to hear the stream.

```
var http = require('http'),
    request = require('request'),
    remote = 'http://stream.radiomedia.com.au:8003/stream';

http.createServer(function (req, res) {

    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'audio/mpeg',
        'Content-Length': 1500
    });
  // http://somewhere.com/noo.bin
  var remoteUrl = remote + req.url;
  request(remoteUrl).pipe(res);
}).listen(8080);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 'Content-Length': 1500

That's your primary problem.  You need to leave the `Content-Length` unspecified, as it's indefinite for your stream.

Also, this will cause the server to use chunked transfer encoding, which many clients these days can handle just fine.  Some can't, so if legacy client compatibility matters to you, you'll have to disable chunked transfer encoding.

> play our icecast stream through nodejs, so that I can read metadata and push another audio file at key parts.

This isn't a trivial thing to do.  MP3 uses the concept of a bit reservoir, so you cannot arbitrarily trim the stream, even on frame boundaries, unless you disable the bit reservoir on the encoder which causes a pretty significant degradation in quality.

For more information, see my answer here:  [Is it possible to splice advertisements or messages dynamically into an MP3 file via a standard GET request?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57548910/362536)

Comment: any chance you could help get the above code as it currently does not play the audio at all

Comment: @RussellHarrower You removed the `Content-Length` response header?  And, what happened, specifically?  What player did you try with?

Comment: nothing it just did not play.

I got it to work by changing the following

  var remoteUrl = remote + req.url;
to 
  var remoteUrl = remote+"?=Player" + req.url;